# How to validate PingFederate JWT Token in .net core(3.1) web api?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, pingfederate

I would like to validate the PingFederate access token at .Net Core(3.1) api end. I am trying to hit the introspect end point as Authority with the token received from the client.

However I am getting the below error
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.

I am new to PingFed, Am I missing any configuration or I have to follow different approach to validate.

I followed below code flow

```
  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Audience = Configuration["Audience"];
                    options.Authority = "https://dev.abc.com/as/introspect.oauth2/";
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        // Validate the JWT Audience
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new X509SecurityKey(x509Cert),
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidIssuer = "https://dev.abc.com"
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true
                    };
                });
```

Comment: What is the value of `Configuration["Audience"]`? Are you sure that issue in this code?

Comment: I am using client Id as audience property.

Comment: Ok, but show us the value of Configuration["Audience"]. Are you sure that issue in this code? You got error about configuration, so, are you sure that issue in this code?

Comment: I am using "dev-test" as Configuration["Audience"]. while registering the application, I have used  "dev-test" as client Id.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't audience be one of your redirect_uri's?
Also your authority should be the Issuer value in your well-known config, in you case more than likely: **"issuer": "https://dev.abc.com"**